# showing MySQL table in SWING frame

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

Once the database was connected...

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `students`"); /*stmt is a Statement*/
ResultSetMetaData md = result.getMetaData();
int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
Vector columns = new Vector(columnCount);
Vector data = new Vector();
Vector row = new Vector(columnCount);

for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++){
   columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));
}

while(result.next()){
  for(int j=1; j<=columnCount; j++){
    row.add(result.getString(j));
    data.addElement(row);
  }
}

JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);   /* Bla Bla Bla about the Table... */
```

This code shows a MySQL table on a SWING frame, but only the First Row is repeating. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you use one instance of `Vector row = new Vector(columnCount);` for all rows. Change your code like next:

```
while (result.next()) {
        Vector row = new Vector(columnCount);
        for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++) {
            row.add(result.getString(j));

        }
        data.addElement(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `Vector row = new Vector(columnCount);` inside the while loop where you are actually adding result to the row as in :

```
while(result.next()){
    Vector row = new Vector(columnCount);
      for(int j=1; j<=columnCount; j++){
        row.add(result.getString(j));
        data.addElement(row);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks shantanuSpark...!

Answer (score 0):

Get the tablemodel and add rows to that and set back the model to the table

e.g.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel )table.getModel();
while (result.next()) {
   Vector data = new Vector();
   for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++) {
       data.add(result.getString(j));
   }
   model.addRow(data);
}
table.setModel(model);
```

or

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);// pass your column names as a vector
while (result.next()) {
   Vector data = new Vector();
   for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++) {
      data.add(result.getString(j));
    }
    model.addRow(data);
}
JTable table = new Jtable(model);
```